# How to check whether my AIX is PPC OR PPC64?

Tags: aix, cpu, 64bit, powerpc

My AIX machine is currently running on 6.1 OS.  I would like to know whether it is on PPC OR PPC64, Is there any command other than arch which gives the information about PPC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`prtconf`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/prtconf.htm) to get the bitness of the running kernel:

```
$ prtconf -k
Kernel Type: 64-bit
```

You could also `ls -l /unix` or `file /unix`, but that's not guaranteed to be the kernel you're currently booted from.

```
$ file /unix
/unix: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
$ ls -l /unix
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     system           21 Dec  9 06:48 /unix -> /usr/lib/boot/unix_64
```

Comment: Starting with AIX 5.3 there is only a 64bit kernel available. To see how to switch the kernel on previous AIX releases (only on 5.1 and 5.2 if I remember correctly) see [Commands to change from 32-bit to 64-bit](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/change32bit.htm?lang=en) or http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21621253
Another way to query the current bitness is via [getconf](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256116)

Answer (score 1):

You may try `uname` like every Unix.